# Plotting realtime with Flot and AJAX - Doesn't plot

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, flot

I'm trying to plot time data using flot JQuery library, but it simply doesn't.

The objective is to get the data from a JSON file like:

```
{
"dados": 150
}
```

The method I'm using is kinda:

```
function getData() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: './data/realtime.json',
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (aferido){
                console.log("Data received. -> var aferido.dados: ", aferido.dados);
                data.push([Date.now(), aferido.dados]); //push something like [timestamp ,value]
                console.log("Data pushed. -> var data: ", data);
                interactive_plot.setData(data);
                interactive_plot.draw();
            }
        });
    }
```

In console the "data" variable is alright, increasing in every update. Ex:

> Data pushed. -> var data:  [Array[2], Array[2], Array[2], Array[2],
>   Array[2], Array[2], Array[2], Array[2], Array[2], Array[2], Array[2],
>   Array[2], Array[2], Array[2], Array[2], Array[2], Array[2], Array[2],
>   Array[2], Array[2], Array[2], Array[2], Array[2], Array[2]]

But the graphic stay static. Any light? I've already tried to change the `setData` parameter, including array brackets, but the problem persists.

Comment: data display doesn't make sense. You show object at top and arrays being logged. What do arrays actually look like?

Comment: also, make sure you use `interactive_plot.setData([data]);` Notice the `[ ]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it is static is because that's how flot works - it doesn't automatically move the x-axis when you add new values

Since you're using time as your y-axis it constantly goes up so you need to change the grid on the fly and make it scroll (auto-advance).

### Examine this simple [JSbin](http://jsbin.com/lidikisove/edit?html,output)

```
    function getRandomData() {
      res.push([i, Math.random()*50])
      i++;
      return res;
    }


    function update() {
      plot.setData([getRandomData()]);

      //Make the x asis move as i increases
      axes = plot.getAxes();
      axes.xaxis.options.max = i;      //also try Math.max(100,i); //Starts to advance after the graph is filled
      axes.xaxis.options.min = i-100;  //and Math.max(0, i-100); 

      plot.setupGrid();
      plot.draw();

      setTimeout(update, updateInterval);  
    }
```

Also, take a look at [this example page](http://www.flotcharts.org/flot/examples/) - ajax and real-time update